# Laravel Contracts Vs Service providers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can i implement laravel contracts and service providers ?

I have a class Cart and its method purchase , the class will of course contain my program structure to which most of my controllers will rely upon.
How can effectively manage dependency injection of this class among other controllers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply reference the class as dependency in your controller. It will be instantiated even if you don't use an interface.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Users\Repository as UserRepository;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * The user repository instance.
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param  UserRepository  $users
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(UserRepository $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }
}
```

If you were to use an interface just make sure your class implements it and simply call use the bind method from the `app` instance in any of your service providers.

```
$this->app->bind(UserRepository::class, EloquentUserRepository::class);
```

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers

Comment: Which directory should i place the class file or the contract file ie this line in your example `use App\Users\Repository as UserRepository;`

Comment: I personally prefer `app/Modules/Mailing/Contracts/Mailer` for the interface and `app/Modules/Mailing/PHPMailMailer` for the class and so on... I do it different for repositories. Wanna know about that too?